# Call Get WebService in Android Project

Tags: android, rest, web-services, wcf, get

I have a Authenticate Rest Service with GET webinvoke. I must send Username and password with my service. I must call this in my project with AsyncTask but i don't know how to send my parameters (username and password) with json type to server. Can i do this? if Yes, how?

My WebService:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Authenticate",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Test<Person> Authenticate(string user,string password)
```

In my code in android project, i convert jsonObject to string and i want to send to server:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("my URL");
response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

I know for Authenticate is best to use POST for security but i want to test and educate ;)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this function  call web-service

```
public static String retrieveStream(String link, String parameters) {
    try {
        link = link.replace(" ", "%20");
        // parameters = parameters.replace(" ", "%20");
        URL url = new URL(link);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStreamWriter request = new OutputStreamWriter(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        request.write(parameters);
        request.flush();
        request.close();

        String line = "";
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        // Response from server after login process will be stored in
        // response variable.
        String response = sb.toString();
        // You can perform UI operations here
        isr.close();
        reader.close();
        return response;

    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but My request method is "GET" , you use "POST".

Comment: Replace POST with GET